# How to know if browser supports webSQL?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-sql

I want to detect if browser supports webSQL, in the same way we can check for indexedDB like below

```
if ( window.indexedDB ) {
    // indexedDB support is available
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/storage/websqldatabase.js) only checks if `"openDataBase"` is available on `window`:

```js
const supports_webSQL = ("openDatabase" in window);

console.log( "supported:", supports_webSQL );
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer @Kaiido, can you please tell me if this solution is cross browser compatible?

Comment: Well there is nothing fancy in there, so yes I guess it's quite safe to use from Netscape, if you replace `const` with `var`. But it makes me think that my stricter version could actually lead to errors being thrown in some cases.